# function in c referencing memory externally allocated

Tags: c, function, malloc

I am splitting the lines as they are red from the input:

```
char **split (char *in, size_t *n, char *delimiter){
    if (delimiter == NULL) delimiter="\t"; // default
    
    char **tokens = malloc(20 * sizeof(char*));

    char *token = strtok(in, delimiter);
    while (token != NULL) {
        tokens[*n] = malloc(30 * sizeof(char*)); // <- why not *tokens[0]
        strcpy(tokens[*n], token);
        (*n)++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

I have the (probably wrong but please explain it to me) idea that allocating (and releasing) different slots of memory on every line is not efficient.

Is it safe (and possible?) to allocate the memory OUTSIDE of the split function and pass a pointer to the array of strings to split function? How (then I would use memset before next line)?

Thank you!

Comment: *I have the (probably wrong but please explain it to me) idea that allocating (and releasing) different slots of memory on every line is not efficient.*  So what if it is?  Do you have any evidence that such inefficiency creates any problems?  You presumably bought the CPU and the cycles it provides for a reason.  And if that means you write easy-to-read, easy-to-maintain code at the cost of some efficiency, that's a good reason for a fast CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe (and possible?) to allocate the memory OUTSIDE of the split function and pass a pointer to the array of strings to split function?

No, because you don't know how large each token will be until you read it nor how many tokens there are. For this reason your code as written is unsafe. It assumes each token is no more than 29 characters and there are no more than 20 tokens.

---

Allocating just the right amount of memory for each token can be solved with `strdup`, [as Chris Dodd explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526305/14660). But that still leaves you allocating a bunch of little pieces of memory.

To minimize allocations you would store all the tokens in a single block of memory. That's what `strtok` does; it modifies the input string replacing the delimiters with nulls. Rather than copying each token, `tokens` would simply point to the start of each token within the original string.

This means `tokens` is pointing to `in` and your function is modifying `in`. I'd leave the choice of whether to duplicate the input string up to the caller.

```
// Don't modify the original, tokens points at a copy.
char **tokens = split(strdup(input), &num_tokens, "\t");

// Modify the original, tokens points at input.
char **tokens = split(input, &num_tokens, "\t");
```

---

That leaves the problem of allocating `tokens`. To do that you either need to know how many tokens there are, or reallocate on the fly.

To minimize CPU you would `realloc` to grow `tokens` as needed.

```
    size_t tokens_size = 1;
    char **tokens = malloc(tokens_size * sizeof(char*));

    *num_tokens = 0;
    for(
        char *token = strtok(in, delimiter);
        token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)
    ) {
        if( *num_tokens >= tokens_size ) {
            tokens_size *= 2;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, tokens_size * sizeof(char*));
        }

        tokens[*num_tokens] = token;

        (*num_tokens)++;
    }
```

As a compromise between efficiency and memory use, rather than reallocating for each token I've doubled the size of tokens each realloc. This will use extra memory, but minimizes reallocations.

---

To minimize allocations, you'd tokenize the string and remember how many tokens there are. Then allocate enough space. Then read the string again storing the pointers to the tokens.

```
    // tokenize in and remember how many there are.
    *num_tokens = 0;
    for(
        char *token = strtok(in, delimiter);
        token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter)
    ) {
        (*num_tokens)++;
    }

    // Allocate exactly enough space.
    char **tokens = malloc(*num_tokens * sizeof(char*));
    
    // Iterate through the tokens and store them.
    char *token = in;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < *num_tokens; i++) {
        // Store a pointer to the token
        tokens[i] = token;
        // Jump ahead the length of the token plus the null.
        token += strlen(token) + 1;
    }
```

For the cost of scanning the input twice you can do just a single malloc.

---

Note: this code would be easier and safer with a struct to contain all the information.

```
typedef struct {
    char *original;
    char **tokens;
    size_t num_tokens;
    size_t tokens_size;
} Tokens;
```

This keeps everything together and you can break it up into functions like `Tokens_init` and `Tokens_free`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the second option, given the allocation for the exact number of tokens and for the strlen of each token, there is no need for memset, right?

Comment: @aerijman Correct. You're not copying anything, just sorting a list of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem that you have is that you're allocating space for 30 pointers in the loop, and then copying a strring into that space.  If that string happens to be longer than 30 pointers (including the terminating NUL), you'll overrun the malloced space and corrupt memory.  If it's shorter, you're just wasting some space.

Better would be to allocate exactly enough space for the string:

```
tokens[*n] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
```

or if you have `strdup` available (POSIX), you could use that to do the malloc and strcpy at once

```
tokens[*n] = strdup(token);
```

You also have the problem that you're only allocating space for 20 tokens (pointers) in the initial allocation -- if you have more than 20, you'll overrun that space as well.  Better would be to `realloc` the pointer array as needed to make it larger.